# How to create infinite running Task loop?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I'd like to create infinite [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.7.2) loop. When any task finish job it will be removed from task list and new task is added to the list. Proposition of my code:

```
// create list of 128 task in queue
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int n = 0; n < 128; n++)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => JOB(n);
}
// wait for finish and add immediately new running task to the list
while (tasks.Count > 0)
{
    Task firstFinishedTask = Task.WhenAny(tasks);
    tasks.Remove(firstFinishedTask);    // line with problem
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => JOB(n);
}
```

The problem is finished task are not removed from the list. They got diffrent [Task.Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.id?view=netframework-4.7.2) and this is huge side effect.

Comment: Sure there is ways of trying to do this, could you however please explain what you are trying to achieve though, my spidey sense tells me there are better ways

Comment: For instance, what is job, why do you need 128 of them, is this IO bound work?

Comment: i would design it so there is an event published when the job is `finished`.  Then deleted `those` jobs. - far easier

Comment: Whatever your *problem* is, I'm certain that creating a fixed pool of 128 tasks to solve it is the wrong solution.

Comment: @TheGeneral yes, this is IO boound. Downloading data from the Internet.

Comment: @JohnB I would like not use events in my application. However if I fail I would redesign algorithm to use events.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it work quite well and does not consume much resources however my previous program worked on inifinite loop with Task.Delay and poorly utilize system resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Task firstFinishedTask = Task.WhenAny(tasks);
```

That's a hideously misnamed variable. `Task.WhenAny` returns a `Task<Task>`. The *outer* `Task` becomes completed when any of the tasks passed to `WhenAny` becomes completed. The *inner* `Task` is the task that caused that to happen. `WhenAny`, by itself, doesn't perform any kind of waiting.

The *usual* way to use `WhenAny` would be to use it with `await` - which always removes the outer `Task` from what you pass it and hands you back the inner content.

If you don't want to use `WhenAny` with `await`, you may be looking for `WaitAny` instead - which blocks your current thread [:-(] and hands you back an index instead of a `Task`, but does at least take care of actually *waiting* for one of the tasks that you passed it to be complete (but as said up-answer, I'd prefer to see `await Task.WhenAny(tasks)` so as to free up this thread)

`tasks` doesn't contain the outer `Task` that `WhenAny` created - that's why your `Remove` attempt fails.